# Grouping by date brings repeated dates for a case count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a simple query but I'm struggling to get the result I wish. I have to count 2 different columns and then group them by date, but I'm not being able to make the count for EACH date, the results repeat the date as many times as that date shows in the table.

I've tried to sum the results of the count and show the date, but that leaded me to the same result. I've tried the distinct clause but that didn't help either.

```
    select 
        distinct(a.dt_agenda) as  sms_date,
        count(case when nvl(a.nr_seq_forma_confirmacao,0) = '1' then 1 end) as sent_sms,
        count(case when a.ds_confirmacao is not null then 1  end) as confirmed_sms
    from
        agenda_consulta a
    where
        trunc(a.dt_agenda,'dd') between :dt_inicio and :dt_fim
    GROUP BY
        A.DT_agenda
        ) t
        order by 1 asc
```

I expect the result to be: 
For example, If I insert into dt_inicio and dt_fim (26/10/2019 and 28/10/2019):

```
sms_date     sent_sms     confirmed_sms      
26/10/2019    1000          2000
27/10/2019    800            350
28/10/2019    900            500
```

Comment: Are your date values all at midnight, or do they have different time components - which seems rather more likely? You're filtering on the truncated date (ignoring time, essentially); but you aren't dong the same for your grouping?

Comment: No, they have different values, that was the problem, I forgot to trunc the date to consider just the date itselft, without the time of the day... That was the reason I was getting so many results, as the fellow bellow suggested. Damn, I feel stupid. hehe. But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to convert to a date:

```
select trunc(a.dt_agenda) as  sms_date,
       count(case when a.nr_seq_forma_confirmacao = 1 then 1 end) as sent_sms,
       count(a.ds_confirmacao) as confirmed_sms
from agenda_consulta a
where trunc(a.dt_agenda, 'dd') between :dt_inicio and :dt_fim
group by trunc(a.dt_agenda)
order by 1 asc;
```

Note that I simplified some of the logic:

- I am guessing that `nr_seq_forma_confirmacao` is a number, so I removed the single quotes on the comparison value.
- `NVL()` is unnecessary, because `NULL = 1` does not evaluate to true.
- For `confirmed_sms`, `count(a.ds_confirmacao)` suffices.

Comment: God, I feel stupid. I didn't realize that. So, without the trunc, even the field is of the date type, it won't consider it a date? Anyway, your tip worked smoothly. Thank you so much.

Comment: DS_confirmacao is text, So I need to check if it's null or not

Comment: The DATE datatype stores point-in-time values (dates and times) in a table. The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the month, the day, the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after midnight). Depending on how you insert your data, the time elements may not allow rows to merge unless you neglect them by truncating.

Comment: @DiegoOdorizzi . . . Strings can be `NULL` (or `''` in Oracle) and `COUNT()` still works.